# Why are there other apps trying to connect to my Azure port?

Tags: java, sockets, azure, firewall

I'm new in Azure and I'm having some troubles here. I'm implementing a JAVA server application on my Azure VM. It's listening for requests from an Android client. I have tested the java server app on my machine and it works great. When I run the same java server application on my Azure VM it looks like there are other apps trying to connect through the same port. I have checked and every single time I change the port it happens again (it happens when the firewall is down, when I don't shut down the firewall it doesn't even receive a single request).

I have a message showing when there is a connection through the port 4567 and couple seconds after I start my server app it shows that there is a connection from a similar IP than the one I have assigned and I haven't yet run my android app.  I configured the endpoints, and I even shut down the firewall and it is giving the same issue. The client app and the server app are working perfectly if I run the server on my local machine. Help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please put something in your title other than your Google search terms.  Something like "Why are there other apps trying to connect to my Azure port?"

Answer (score 0):

What you might be seeing is the way Azure manages/monitors public Endpoints. When you expose a public endpoint for your VM Azure will behind the scenes periodically test that port to make sure it is up and listening for traffic. This is part of the way Azure manages load balancing for public Endpoints. Because of this, if you watch connections to your the local port on your VM to which the public endpoint is mapped, you will see connections from Azure internal IPs.